# Extracting member names from HDF5 compound datasets with h5py

Tags: hdf5, h5py, hdf

I am trying to extract compound datasets from multiple .hd5 files. Initially, I used HD5View 2.9, which lets you open up datasets as tables and save them as .txt files; however, it does not save the column headers, i.e., "sensor," "framerate," etc as in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ozND.png

So now I am attempting to write an h5py script that will read in these datasets along with the column headers, also known as "member names," but it seems to be more complicated than I was expecting. I have successfully written scripts that extract simple datasets containing only integers, in which the column headers are just indices I don't care about. But I am not even sure how to gain access to member names using h5py.

Comment: In `h5py` the data is saved as `datasets` (and attributes) of multiply nested `groups`.  It treats groups like Python dictionaries.  The `group` `visit` and `visititems` methods may make the exploration easier.

Comment: Thanks. I already have code that walks through each group and extracts datasets using visititems - but it just doesn't seem to have access to member names (column headers) for compound datasets. It's not part of the dataset, attributes, or group metadata.

Comment: Field names are found in the `dtype`, same as in numpy structured arrays.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html

when you use `.keys()`,

you can get `"KeysView( < HDF5 group "../path" (n members)> )"`

After that,

```
list(KeysView(< HDF5 group "../path" (n members) >))  --> get memebers name
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names are found in the dtype, same as in numpy structured arrays. Credits to @hpaulj